# Remark after proof of existence of free groups (page-21,Clara loeh)

Tags: free-groups, geometric-group-theory

### Context

> Definition 2.2.4 (Free groups, universal property). Let $S$ be a set. A group $F$ containing $S$ is freely generated by $S$ if $F$ has the following universal property: For every group $G$ and every map $\varphi: S → G$ there is a unique group
> homomorphism $\varphi: F\dashrightarrow G$ extending $\varphi$:
>
> [image]
>
> Proposition 2.2.6 (Free groups, uniqueness). Let $S$ be a set. Then, up to canonical isomorphism, there is at most one group freely generated by $S$.

### The doubt

After the proof of the proposition mentioned in context, the following remark is given:

> These isomorphisms are canonical in the following sense: They induce the identity map on $S$, and they are (by the uniqueness part of the universal property) the only isomorphisms between $F$ and $F'$ extending the identity
> on $S$

In the above, $F$ and $F'$ are two free groups and $S$ is the generating set of them. The isomorphisms are the map from $F$ to $F'$ and back. My questions are the following:

1. How does isomorphism 'induce' an identity map on $S$? In what sense is the word inducing used.
2. How does isomorphism extend the identity on $S$?

Sorry if these are very noob questions! I am still a beginner at this topic. One may find the book [here](http://www.mathematik.uni-regensburg.de/loeh/ggt_book/ggt_book_draft.pdf). It's also available from amazon.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a free group $F$ on a generating set $S$, then the elements of $S$ are (or can be seen as) elements of $F$. That is what the inclusion map $S \hookrightarrow F$ indicates.

(Note that in your Definition 2.2.4 it is really given that $S$ is subset of $F$.)

Now suppose that you have two free groups $F$ and $F'$ on the same generating set $S$. Then the point is that there is exactly one isomorphism between $F$ and $F'$ such that the restriction of that isomorphism to $S$ is the identity on $S$.

This is what is meant by 'induces the identity map on $S$'. Another way of saying this is that 'it extends the identity on $S$'. It makes sense because $S$ is a subset of both $F$ and $F'$.

So, just to expand what Proposition 2.2.6 is saying, avoiding the use of the word 'canonical' and being explicit about how you should interpret 'at most one':

Proposition 2.2.6.
Let $S$ be a set. Let $F$ and $F'$ both be groups that are freely generated by $S$. Then

1. there is an isomorpism $\phi \colon F \to F'$ with the property that $\phi(s) = s$ for all $s \in S$;
2. if $\psi \colon F \to F'$ is an (other) isomorphism with the property that $\psi(s) = s$ for all $s \in S$, then $\phi = \psi$.

Comment: How do we the restriction of isomorphism between free groups is infact the identity map on S?

Comment: It is not true that the restriction of an arbitrary isomorphism between $F$ and $F'$ to $S$ is the identity on $S$. However, there exists (exactly) one such isomorphism. That follows from the universal property.

Comment: Universal property says unique group homomorphism and from that we can find there exists a unique two side isomorphism between F and F'. How does thie relate to there being only a unique identity homomorphism?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. But note that the universal property does not say that there is a unique homomorphism. It says that there is a unique homomorphism extending $\phi$. But, really, this is the same remark as I made above, so I'm not sure if this is where your confusion is. The trick is to apply the universal property of $F$ to the inclusion map from $S$ to $F'$ (and also the other way around) giving a (unique) homomorphism from $F$ to $F'$ extending the identity on $S$.

Comment: I'll come back to this answer in some hours. I just want to say thank you for the help.

Comment: So you are restricting the homomorphism map from F to F' onto S for the input and output? but how is this an identity?. Secondly aren't there two isomorphism between F and F'? One from F to F' and one from F' to F

Comment: Yes, you restrict both domain and codomain to $S$ (although it is more precise to say that you restrict the domain and then the image turns out to be $S$) and it is an identity on $S$ because the universal property of $F$ says that it is; for $\phi \colon S \to G$ you take the inclusion of $S$ into $F'$. And yes, there is an isomorphism from $F$ to $F'$ and one the other way around: its inverse.